# Using Mathematica to derive the PDF of A Cos(x)

Tags: probability-or-statistics

Let Y = cos(X), where X is uniformly distributed in the
interval (0, 2 pi]. Find the pdf of Y.

I know the answer but want to verify using *Mathematica*.

[image]

Comment: As PlatoManiac has shown `TransformedDistribution` you can also show noting:
`D[ArcCos[x],x]` yields: $\frac{-1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$, then symmetry about $x=\pi$ yields : $2 \int_{\cos \pi}^{\cos 2\pi}\frac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{1-x^2}}\ dx= \int_{-1} ^{1}\frac{1}{\pi\sqrt{1-x^2}}\ dx$, hence PDF as per PlatoManiac.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. but i copied the code to the mathemetica notebook ( version 7 i use), showing syntax error. TransformedDistribution available in 7?

Answer (score 11):

The [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TransformedDistribution.html#2067307076) on `TransformedDistribution` will guide you through.

```
d = TransformedDistribution[Cos[x], x \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{0, 2 Pi}]];
pdf = PDF[d, x]
```

Output will be this 
$$\begin{array}{cc}
 f_y(x)=\{ & 
\begin{array}{cc}
 \text{Indeterminate} & x=-1\lor x=1 \\
 \frac{1}{\pi  \sqrt{1-x^2}} & -1<x<1 \\
\end{array}
 \\
\end{array}$$

You can plot the pdf.

```
Plot[Evaluate[pdf], {x, -1, 1}, Filling -> Axis]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. but i copied the code to the mathemetica notebook ( version 7 i use), showing syntax error.  TransformedDistribution available in 7?

Comment: No, TransformedDistribution was introduced in version 8. This information is noted at the bottom of the online reference page.